# Xcode 7 doesn't show images added

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This has to be the worst bug I ran into with Xcode 7.

In previous versions of Xcode 6 or below, if I needed to add my pngs, jpgs to a project then I would do Xcode -> File -> Add files to Project -> select a folder where I had all my images in and add that. I was then able to use those images using code

```
NSString* headerStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_black.png"];
UIImage *myImg = [UIImage imageNamed:headerStr]; 
NSLog(@"myImg: %@ ...", myImg);
```

Now check this out, if I try to add my pics folder in Xcode 7 it shows up blue. Why is it blue? If I try the code above then nslog displays

```
myImg: null ...
```

I mean what is going on? It never displayed any of the images I added.

Just for the heck of it I deleted that blue folder and created a new folder in my project by doing right click -> New group and then added all the pics to it and then it works. Is this a monster bug with this great Xcode 7?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are adding your folder as reference thats why its shown in **blue**.

Delete the "pics2" folder. And try to add the folder again inside the project and select below options.

[image]

Comment: actually no. I am not adding it as a reference rather I am adding as Xcode -> File -> Add files to Project -> select a folder. I tried dragging and dropping and checking copy items, still it has the same effect

Comment: Did you also check Create groups ?